# I'm getting "Null is not an object" when retrieving JSON data yet path is correct

Tags: json, image, react-native, null

I am attempting to retrieve JSON data in my app. Data is returned succcesfully when using:

```react
<Text style={styles.font}> {item.show.name}</Text>
```

but I am now attempting to return an image. The correct path to the image in the JSON is:

```json
item.show.image.original
```

But I am getting an error that reads:

```
“Null is not a object (evaluating item.show.image.original)
```

I have tried changing the path name, adding indexes, putting the path in a string but nothing is changing. Here is the code:

```react
<View>
      {data ? (<View style={styles.resultsContainer}>
    <FlatList
      numColumns= '3'
      data={data}
      renderItem={({item}) => (
        <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.show}onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Shows')}>    
        <View style={styles.text}>
          <Text style={styles.font}> {item.show.name}</Text>
         </View>
          <Image 
          style={styles.resultImage} source={{uri: item.show.image.original }} />

      </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
      
      />
    </View>
```

And here is the JSON

```json
[
  {
    "score": 17.915743,
    "show": {
      "id": 5631,
      "url": "https://www.tvmaze.com/shows/5631/car-sos",
      "name": "Car S.O.S",
      "type": "Documentary",
      "language": "English",
      "genres": [],
      "status": "To Be Determined",
      "runtime": 60,
      "premiered": "2013-02-07",
      "officialSite": "http://natgeotv.com/uk/car-sos",
      "schedule": {
        "time": "20:00",
        "days": [
          "Thursday"
        ]
      },
      "rating": {
        "average": 7.9
      },
      "weight": 95,
      "network": {
        "id": 242,
        "name": "National Geographic Channel",
        "country": {
          "name": "United Kingdom",
          "code": "GB",
          "timezone": "Europe/London"
        }
      },
      "webChannel": null,
      "externals": {
        "tvrage": 35146,
        "thetvdb": 266851,
        "imdb": null
      },
      "image": {
        "medium": "https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/100/250748.jpg",
        "original": "https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/100/250748.jpg"
      }
```

Why is my image not returning? I am rather confused as the text is returning perfectly but not the image.

Comment: what do you get if you do `console.log(item.show.image)`?

Answer (score 0):

But it looks like there is no image key in the "show" object in the JSON you provided. It looks like you face an image path under item.image.original or item.image.medium.

Comment: But then I recieve 'TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.image.original')'

Answer (score 0):

I got your expected result , I don't know what are you applying in images style please apply `width` and `height` of image I hope you will get your image

Here is my complete small code which is only for testing for purpose

```
import React, { Component } from 'react' import {FlatList,Text,Image} from 'react-native' class Test extends Component{ constructor(props){ super(props)this.state={
        data:[
            {
              "score": 17.915743,
              "show": {
                "id": 5631,
                "url": "https://www.tvmaze.com/shows/5631/car-sos",
                "name": "Car S.O.S",
                "type": "Documentary",
                "language": "English",
                "genres": [],
                "status": "To Be Determined",
                "runtime": 60,
                "premiered": "2013-02-07",
                "officialSite": "http://natgeotv.com/uk/car-sos",
                "schedule": {
                  "time": "20:00",
                  "days": [
                    "Thursday"
                  ]
                },
                "rating": {
                  "average": 7.9
                },
                "weight": 95,
                "network": {
                  "id": 242,
                  "name": "National Geographic Channel",
                  "country": {
                    "name": "United Kingdom",
                    "code": "GB",
                    "timezone": "Europe/London"
                  }
                },
                "webChannel": null,
                "externals": {
                  "tvrage": 35146,
                  "thetvdb": 266851,
                  "imdb": null
                },
                "image": {
                  "medium": "https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/100/250748.jpg",
                  "original": "https://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/100/250748.jpg"
                }
          }
          }
          ]
    }
}
renderItem=({item})=>(
    <>
    <Text>{item.show.image.original}</Text>
    <Image source={{uri:item.show.image.original}} style={{width:200,height:200}} />
    </>

)
render(){
    return(
        <FlatList
        data={this.state.data}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        />
    )
}}export default Test
```

I hope it will be helpful for you